# When does passive trace start in Uplink?

Tags: uplink

In Uplink, I've heard that banks have the fastest passive trace times in the game; but if you have proxy bypass and monitor bypass, the active trace never starts. Do passive traces start from when the active trace would normally start, or do they start when you disconnect from the target host? (e.g. do I have to worry about being connected to such a system for a long time when not being traced?)

Comment: Yay for uplink!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A passive trace starts when the victim discovers the damage has been done (e.g. data destroyed, large money transfers) if they have a trail. Nuking the target eliminates the trail (either via deleting system files and rebooting or running Revelation). If you can, use Log Deleter v.4 just to be sure. If you have a respectable tunnel chain, a passive trace can take days. If you're careful not to pick up any active traces, you can do a bunch of jobs in the space of several hours without worrying, then delete the logs on one of your first hops to prevent any possibility of a passive trace succeeding (The InterNIC server is best for this because they will never trace you).

Banks are a special case, though. You only have 2 minutes to eliminate the money trail by using Log Deleter to remove the statements. Having an account at the same bank as your target will save you a few precious seconds. After you've done that, don't forget to remove the usual log trails, though that is not as time critical as removing the money trail.

Comment: Banks are special in that you have exactly 2 minutes to cover up the money trail before they rustle your jimmies. 120 seconds from the moment you transfer the money to yourself, specifically.

Comment: +1 -- I was referring to the connection trace; if you're robbing the bank (rather than just checking the size of someone's loan) that makes sense it'd be different. Thanks!

Comment: @lunboks I'm not sure, but it felt like 30 seconds at most when I played. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @kotekzot I just looked it up in the source code, because I wanted to answer this question, damn you! `#define TIME_TOCOVERBANKROBBERY 2 MINUTES // Player has this long to cover his tracks`

Comment: @lunboks damn, that's some dedication! Updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: For reference, the code snippet [lunboks quotes](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60573/when-does-passive-trace-start-in-uplink#comment85573_60578) is line 380 of the file *source/game/data/data.h* on the [Uplink Developer CD](http://www.introversion.co.uk/uplink/developer/developercd.html).